# Filter doesn't work on Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, filter, laravel-routing

I am having trouble getting filters to work in Laravel 4.

Here is my code:

```
/**
* filters.php
**/
Route::filter('isAdmin', function()
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        if(Auth::user()->level == 'User')
            return Redirect::to('/');
    }
    return Redirect::to('/auth/login');

});  Route::when('admin/*', 'isAdmin');

/**
* routes.php
**/

Route::get('admin/home', 'AdminController@home'));
Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@home');
```

I don't understand why this filter doesn't work. This filter are totally ignored in route `/admin/*`. I want that only a logged admin can see the admin panel.

Comment: I've moved your code into your question, so it will still be readable if the external link breaks. If you would do that for all future questions, that would be great - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the slash, your filter is working with 'admin/home' but not with 'admin' route. Write this for both routes to be filtered.

```
Route::when('admin*', 'isAdmin');
```

or better

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'isAdmin'), function()
{
    Route::get('home', 'AdminController@home'));
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@home');
});
```